# Crear una expresion regular para validar nombres

Tags: javascript, regex

estoy intentando crear una expresion regular que me permita validar nombres simples o compuestos pero no funciona como lo necesito.

Logre armar la siguiente expresion regular:

`^([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑa-zñáéíóúñ]{1,}'?-?[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑa-zñáéíóú]+[\s]*)+$`

Pero no se como pueda mejorarla para evitar lo siguiente:

- Evitar que se pueda utilizar mas de un simbolo en el grupo

Ejemplo:

> **O'Neil-s**

Acepta - No deberia aceptar dos simbolos diferentes en el grupo

- Evitar que se pueda utilizar el mismo simbolo en el grupo

Ejemplo:

> **O'Neil's**

Acepta - No deberia aceptar dos simbolos iguales en el grupo

- Evitar que se pueda utilizar mas de un simbolo en los siguientes grupos

Ejemplo:

> **jean d-maria'sg**

Acepta - No deberia aceptar dos simbolos en el segundo grupo

Alguien me puede ayudar, ya he probado todas las formas y no he logrado solucionar

Gracias

Comment: Para que la comunidad pueda colaborarte debes definir los requerimientos de las entradas que deberían hacer match con la expresion regular y cuales no deberian hacer match. Los ejemplos ayudan a comprender laa definiciones, pero no son la definición misma ni la remplazan.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, logre reestructurar mejor la pregunta, la idea principal es solo poder usar un simbolo (excepto inicio o fin) sobre el grupo para hacer match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresion regular puede ser la siguiente:

`^([A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+['\-]{0,1}[A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+)(\s+([A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+['\-]{0,1}[A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+))*$`

La cual hace match con las siguientes reglas

- Una o mas palabras separadas con por lo menos un espacio
- Cada palabra debe cumplir las siguientes reglas:

  - Los caracteres permitidos mas de una vez en cada palabra son `[A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]` (Letras mayusculas y minúsculas, incluidos las vocales con tilde y las Ñ)
  - Los únicos símbolos permitidos son el apóstrofo y el guión `['\-]` y estos se permiten a lo sumo una vez `{0,1}`
  - Asumiendo que cada palabra debe empezar y terminar con una letra la expresion lleva el cuantificador `+` . En caso de permitirse empezar y/o terminar con los símbolos permitidos los cuantificadores deberían cambiarse por `*` (cero o más)

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio Ortega, la expresión funciona muy bien